# Will a local Handler with postDelayed get garbage collected before the runnable is called

Tags: java, android

Is the following a safe thing to do.  It sure is handy, but can the Handler get garbage collected before the runnable runs?

```
public void dodelayed()
{
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            //do something
        }
    }, 50);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it is **not** GCed. It is just fine to do it this way.

Little longer explanation, to avoid confusions:

Although you don't store the reference to the handler, it is stored somewhere else. In the method [sendMessageAtTime](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#sendMessageAtTime%28android.os.Message,%20long%29), which is called from inside `postDelayed`, before the handler puts the message in the message queue, it assigns itself in the `target` field of the message, so there is still a reference to the Handler, and it is not GCed:

```
public boolean sendMessageAtTime(Message msg, long uptimeMillis)
{
    //...
    if (queue != null) 
    {
        msg.target = this; // here the reference to the handler is assigned 
        sent = queue.enqueueMessage(msg, uptimeMillis);
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: The OP is asking whether the `Handler` *itself* might be garbage-collected. I see nothing in `Handler` itself that would prevent this.

Comment: @CommonsWare - take a look at http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/os/Handler.java#Handler.sendMessageAtFrontOfQueue%28android.os.Message%29 which is called from post delayed. The reference of the handler is stored in the message itself, so it will not be garbage collected, until this reference will be removed, or the message itself will be GCed.

Comment: Ah, so it's tied to `postDelayed()`. OK, that makes sense -- thanks!